# Append module to cloud_config_modules in user-data (cloud-init) while provisioning an instance

Tags: centos, devops, cloud-init

I am trying to add a repository using `yum_repos` but the `cloud.cfg` file shipped by vendor does not seem to have the module mentioned in the configuration resulting in cloud-init process skipping the `cc_yum_add_repo` module.

I have tried the following configuration but it does not work.

```
#cloud-config

cloud_config_modules:
 - yum_repos

yum_repos:
  elrepo-kernel:
    name: Elrepo Kernel Repo
    baseurl: https://elrepo.org/linux/kernel/el7/$basearch/
    repo_gpgcheck: 1
    enable_gpgcheck: true
    gpgkey: https://www.elrepo.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-elrepo.org
    enabled_metadata: 1

packages:
 - kernel-ml
package_update: true
package_reboot_if_required: true
```

The objective of this cloud-config file is to update the kernel on first boot automatically. I can run it after first boot using `cloud-init --file /path/to/user-data.txt single --name cc_yum_add_repo` but it does not run automatically.

Any help/leads would be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide the error you get (as close to the exact output) ?

Comment: @azbarcea, there are no errors, it just skips the `yum_repos` portion and attempts to install the `kernel-ml` package which isn't available because the repository was not added.

Answer (score 0):

If the vendor failed to provide the yum repo module config with their image for a RHEL-family distro, you might want to notify the vendor so it can get fixed.

In the meantime, you can add the module to your `cloud.cfg` manually. On a Centos 8 Stream image I see this in the `cloud_config_modules` section under `rh_subscription`:

```yaml
cloud_config_modules:
 - mounts
 - locale
 - set-passwords
 - rh_subscription
 - yum-add-repo
```

Note: Since undefined keys are ignored in user-data cloud-config, I would expect `cloud_config_modules` in your aforementioned config to be ignored.